# Find visible elements in slider div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a pretty standard slider component which slider UL.

I want to add active classes to only visible elements in viewport. I tried googling but all in vail. Is anyone able to shed some light on this please?

[image]

Following is the sliding code:

```
// get all lists that slider was initialised on
$lists = $(this.container).find('> ul');

// get current left position of list
currentPos = $lists.position().left;

// new left position of list is width of a page times target page number
newLeftPos = currentPos - (530 * (newPageNum-1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($("li").is(":visible")){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because li's are always visible?

Comment: Visible elements in viewport http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Comment: Thanks, last link you provided did the job. Thanks.